# How to prove $X(t)$ is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose $X(t)\in M_n(\Bbb R), t\in\Bbb R$ and is **continuous, invertible** at every point on the real line, if the equation 
$$X(t)X(s)=X(t+s)$$
holds for all $t,s\in\Bbb R$, prove that there exists a constant square matrix $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ such that 
$$X(t)=\exp(At)$$

Now I've done most of the major work: I have worked out $X(0)=I$,  if $X'(0)$ exists, then $X$ must fit this DE for $X$: $$X'=X'(0)X$$ Note that all solutions to this DE can be represented as $$X=\exp(X'(0)t)C$$, so $C=I$ will be determined by $X(0)=I$, which yields the desired result.

The only problem is I do not know how to show $X$ is differentiable on the real line, or in particular, at any given point, say $0$.

The only way seems to be checking  by definition, so I must show, for instance, that
$$\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{X(\Delta t)-I}{\Delta t}$$
converges.

But since I don't have any information about what particular form $X$ may take, so there's noting I can do with this expression.

Can you help me? Or is there any alternative methods that can avoid differentiation? Best regards!

Comment: Which results did the "most of the major work" you have already done produce?

Comment: @HenningMakholm if $X'(0)$ exists, then $X$ must fit this DE for $X$: $$X'=X'(0)X$$ *all* solutions to this DE can be represented as $$X=\exp(X'(0)t)C$$, so $C=I$ is determined by $X(0)=I$, which yields the desired result.

Comment: You should edit this information into the question instead of giving it as comments. It is vital for knowing _what you are actually asking for help with_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm alright. I'll add it to the post. Thanks for pointing out:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Averaging a function makes it smoother. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that for every $a > 0$ the function

$$Y(t) = \frac{1}{a}\int_t^{t+a} X(s)\,ds = \frac{1}{a}\int_0^a X(s+t)\,ds\tag{1}$$

is differentiable. Since $X$ is a homomorphism, we can write $(1)$ as

$$Y(t) = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a X(s+t)\,ds = \frac{1}{a}\int_0^a X(s)X(t)\,ds = \underbrace{\Biggl(\frac{1}{a}\int_0^a X(s)\,ds\Biggr)}_{B_a}\cdot X(t).\tag{2}$$

If we can choose $a > 0$ so that $B_a$ is invertible, then we can write $(2)$ as

$$X(t) = B_a^{-1}\cdot Y(t),\tag{3}$$

which then shows the differentiability of $X$.

Why can we choose $a > 0$ so that $B_a$ is invertible?

Comment: $X(0)=Id_n$, so for $a$ small enough, $B_a$ is close to the identity and invertible.

Comment: As Thomas pointed out, since $X$ is continuous, by MVT (to each entry of $X$), when $a$ is small enough $B_a$ is close enough to $X(0)=I$. Thanks for your answer!